# CookieAuthentication and AspNet Core 2.0 migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-core, migration

I can't find a way how to migrate the application from aspnet core 1.1 to 2.0 which is using cookie authentication.

Most useful resources I already know are:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x#cookie-based-authentication
- https://github.com/aspnet/announcements/issues/262
- https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2128 (my own question)

Unfortunately, I am still stuck. Here is how I do it:
In Startup.cs `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`I have:

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfigureNamedOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, CookieAuthenticationOptionsSetup>();
```

and later:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();
```

The `CookieAuthenticationOptionsSetup` class implements `IConfigureNamedOptions` and sets `options.Cookie.Name = "test"` inside the `Configure` method.
I event tried to manually create and set Name property to "Cookies".

**If I try to change the name of cookie with lambda expression inside Startup.cs `AddCookie` method, it works as expected.** But if I don't, the `CookieAuthenticationOptionsSetup` is never used and the default cookie name (.AspNetCore.Cookies) is used.

What I am missing?

Comment: Please try to register your custom `CookieAuthenticationOptions` **after** calling `AddCookie`.

Comment: I've just tried that. No success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`AddCookie()`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieExtensions.cs#L29) by default calls [`AuthenticationBuilder.AddScheme`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/AuthenticationBuilder.cs#L37). From there, we can learn how the options would be ideally registered if you passed them to the `AddCookie` call:

```
Services.Configure(authenticationScheme, configureOptions);
```

So let’s take a look at how `Services.Configure` works with named options. What [ultimately gets registered](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L68) on the service collection are `IConfigureOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>>`.

So I would guess that is the exact type that is being looked up later when the options are resolved via DI. And in fact, [that is the exact type](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/OptionsFactory.cs#L22) that is being request by the `OptionsFactory` that is being used by the `OptionsMonitor` which is [requested by the authentication handler](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L35).

So, tl;dr: You are registering your custom configuration as the wrong type. You should register it as an `IConfigureOptions<>`:

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, CookieAuthenticationOptionsSetup>();
```

Note of course that your `CookieAuthenticationOptionsSetup` needs to implement [`IConfigureNamedOptions`](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/IConfigureNamedOptions.cs) properly and respond to a `Configure` call with your scheme name (`CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`).

Comment: Yes, you are right, I had to implement IConfigureNamedOptions<T> but register as IConfigureOptions<T>! Additional comments in a separate answer.

Comment: @Zygimantas Thank you very much for the additional bounty! That really wasn’t necessary but the gesture is all the more appreciated! Thank you and I’m glad you managed to get it working :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45770419/cookieauthentication-and-aspnet-core-2-0-migration#answer-45785207), I also had to add `Name` property to the class which implements `IConfigureNamedOptions<T>` and set it in `public void Configure(string name, CookieAuthenticationOptions options)` method.

Few additional notes for those who will have the same problem:

To apply `Authorize` attribute globally, authentication scheme must be added (worked without it previously):

```
services.AddMvcCore(a =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().AddAuthenticationSchemes(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
    a.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

To use `IsAuthenticated` property inside middleware, `app.UseAuthentication()` must be called before registering the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly clear what is the question...
But if you want just to set cookie name (or other options) and really do not need to implement `IConfigureNamedOptions` try something like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "TestName";
}
```

Comment: Setting a cookie name is a simplified example. I use separate class because the configuration is too complicated for lambda. The question is: why cookie settings, as a class, is not injected.